# unexpected end of input error while passing json data from a JS each loop to a JS function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a jquery foreach appended list in a table. What I want is to pass the full object that I am getting from an ajax success function. But when I try to pass the Object as a parameter to a different JS function, the parameter gets unexpected end of input.

This is my appended table:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "@Url.Content("~/Estimate/GetOffsetLetterHeadCost")",
    data: $('#OffLetterHeadForm').serialize(),
    datatype: "json",
    traditional: true,
    success: function(data) {
        var Json = data;
        $.each(Json, function(index, obj) {
            var row = '<tr>' + '<td><b>' + obj.VendorName + '</b></td>' 
                + '<td><label id="machineId' + index + '">' 
                + obj.MachineName + ' </label></td>' 
                + '<td><input type="button" value="Order" id="btn' 
                + index + '"onclick="SaveOffsetOrder(' 
                + JSON.stringify(obj) + ')"/></td></tr>';

                $("#AllVendorsList").append(row);
        });
    }
});

<table id="AllVendorsList"></table>

function SaveOffsetOrder(obj) {  
  // do something with obj
}
```

At input close I am getting unexpexted end of input. Please help. I am new to javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14k8b.png)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that JSON.stringify(obj) doesn't escape quotes like this \" and the result is invalid html.

I suggest using jQuery onclick binding, so you don't have to stringify obj and then parse it.

Solution: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/452188/

```js
var Json = [{
  VendorName: 'kia',
    MachineName: 'ceed'
  }, {
  VendorName: 'dacia',
    MachineName: 'logan'
}];

$.each(Json, function(index, obj) {
  var row = '<tr>' + '<td> <b>' + obj.VendorName + '</b></td>' + '<td><label id="machineId' + index + '">' + obj.MachineName + '</label></td>' + '<td><input type="button" value="Order" id="btn' + index + '"/></td></tr >';

  $("#AllVendorsList").append(row);
  $("#btn" + index).on('click', $.proxy(SaveOffsetOrder, this, obj));
});

function SaveOffsetOrder(obj) {
  console.info(obj);
}
```

```html
<table id="AllVendorsList"></table>
```

Comment: its not calling the function..what should i do

Comment: It works in fidle, just open console and when you click order, you will see the object loged from function.

Comment: i tried in fiddle also,but its not firing the function on order click

Comment: Well, there has to be some other problem in your code.

Comment: i am clicking this on a modal popup..will it make any difference?

Comment: It shouldn't, can you share more of your code? Or did you solve it already?

Comment: can i share it on Anydesk or Team Viewer.if you dont mind

Comment: I am sharing a text on google drive..please check this

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mq6g1puB_eAtBFIpkmacQ9dJEZqaghtd/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

there are a lot of syntax problem. First of all, It's not clear where you have putted your js functions. If it's an .html file, your code should be:

```
<table id="AllVendorsList"></table>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.ajax({

      type: "post",
      url: "@Url.Content("~/Estimate/GetOffsetLetterHeadCost
      ")",
      data: $('#OffLetterHeadForm').serialize(),
      datatype: "json",
      traditional: true,
      success: function(data) {

        var Json = data;

        $.each(Json, function(index, obj) {
            var row = '<tr>' + '<td> <b>' + obj.VendorName + '</b>  </td>  ' + 
            '<td><label  id="machineId' + index + '">' + obj.MachineName + '  
            < / label > < /td > ' + '<td> <input type="button"   value="Order" 
            id="btn' + index + '"onclick ="SaveOffsetOrder(' + 
        JSON.stringify(obj) + ')" / > < /td></tr > ';

        $("#AllVendorsList").append(row);

        });

      }
    });
   function SaveOffsetOrder(obj) {  
   // do something with obj
   }
</script>
```

So your error is related to syntax problems.

Comment: ..i have added a image int the question ..please see the image